# Get subscription price of simple subscription product and its sign up fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscription

I am using woocommerce subscriptions plugin. I want to get the subscription price plus the sign up fee of a product of type "simple subscription".

I am able to get subscription price using this function :

```
<?php WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_price( $product ) ?>
```

However I want to have the sign up fee also, so that I can add the prices together and display.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the `class-wc-product-subscription.php` file. There are two functions `get_sign_up_fee_including_tax()` and `get_sign_up_fee_exluding_tax()`.

So you should be able to get the sign up fee like so:

```
$product->get_sign_up_fee_including_tax();
```

Sidenote, I *think* you can get the pure price from `$product->get_price()` but you will need Subscriptions specific functions to get the subscriptions strings. ---